# Gallio 64bit Plattform and 32bit dll Sonar and OpenCover BadImageException

Tags: 32bit-64bit, sonarqube, gallio, badimageformatexception, opencover

We using Gallio for test execution. All projects under test and all test projects are compiled as 32bit Version. The Buildserver is Win2008 R2 64bit.
Gallio is installed as 32bit version. 
Gallio is startet through Sonar. As coverageTool we use OpenCover.
As the title says the BadImageFormat Exception is the Problem. Then Trying to run, the .Net\Framework64\ folder is used. But all targets are set to 32bit architecture.
After two days of testing and researching I tryed different Gallio Versions:
32bit installer
64bit installer
Gallio Bundle Zip
I tried to rename the Gallio.Host.x86.exe to Gallio.Host.exe
I tried to force Gallio to run in 32bit mode via CorFlags Galio.Echo.exe /32BIT+ /FORCE
(Using /FORCE will invalidate the signature of this image and will require the assambly to be resigned)

Has anybody a Idea what I'am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running Sonar v3.0 (or greater), as most 64-bit issues were resolved with that release.  <strike>I would also suggest moving to PartCover as your coverage tool.</strike> *(Edit: PartCover is the way to go now)*

Comment: Why user PartCover instead? (Besides PartCover is no longer in work:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/)

Comment: I believe at the time there were issues with OpenCover. But since then, most/all have been addressed.  I use PartCover and recommend others do as well. (see http://www.wrightfully.com/setting-up-sonar-analysis-for-c-projects/)

Answer (score 0):

> Then Trying to run, the .Net\Framework64\ folder is used

What do you mean by "used"?  Even if every executable is correctly marked and run as a 32-bit process, if one of them tries to load a binary in the Framework64 folder (all 64-bit binaries) a BadImageFormatException would be expected.

Comment: This looks like a comment, not an answer. Please use comments instead! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming both "Gallio.Host.Elevated.x86.exe", "Gallio.Host.x86.exe" to "Gallio.Host.Elevated.exe", "Gallio.Host.exe". That worked for me - [running nunit tests (x86) with gallio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112747/running-nunit-tests-x86-with-gallio/17198945#17198945)